# Is total energy conserved in a reversed Hooke's law $F=+k x$ problem?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

The following case is similar to the harmonic motion differential equation, however, the minus sign changes the problem
\begin{align}
m \frac{d^2x}{d t^2}-k x =0
\end{align}
Now, the question is whether the total energy $E$ is conserved or not.
Note that, solving the differential equation yields:
\begin{align}
y^2-\omega^2 x^2=C
\end{align}

where $y=\frac{dx}{dt}$, $\omega^2=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$, and $C$ is an integration constant. It is clear that the previous equation shows that $T-V=\text{Constant}$.

Regarding the conservation equation i.e. $E=T+V$, is it possible to show that the total energy is conserved here too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The following case is similar to the harmonic motion differential equation, however, the minus sign changes the problem
> \begin{align}
> m \frac{d^2x}{d t^2}-k x =0
> \end{align}
> Now, the question is whether the total energy $E$ is conserved or not.

Yes, it is. But you have to make sure you understand what $E$ means.

While $E=T+U$, as usual, the potential energy in this case is **not** $U=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$. Rather, the potential energy is:
$$
U = -\frac{1}{2}kx^2\;,
$$
which follows from the **definition** of potential energy:
$$
F = -\frac{dU}{dx} = +kx\;.
$$

Therefore the Lagrangian is:
$$
L = T - U = \frac{1}{2}m{\dot x}^2 +\frac{1}{2}kx^2\;
$$
and the Hamiltonian is:
$$
H = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}\dot x - L = T + U = E = \frac{1}{2}m{\dot x}^2 - \frac{1}{2}kx^2\;.
$$

And, obviously, you could have arrived at the same expressions above by considering the usual simple-harmonic oscillator Lagrangian and Hamiltonian and making the replacement $k\to-k$.

In our current case (where the force is $F=+kx$) the quantity
$$
\frac{1}{2}m{\dot x}^2 - \frac{1}{2}kx^2
$$
is conserved since it is equal to the Hamiltonian, and the Hamiltonian is conserved for the usual reasons. (I.e., since $\frac{dH}{dt} = \dot x\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}\right)+\ddot x\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}\right) - \frac{dL}{dt}=-\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}=0$.)

---

Although the Hamiltonian (which also equals the total energy $E=T+U$) is conserved, it is not really a great idea to interpret $H$ or $E$ as an energy if $k$ is positive (meaning the $U=-kx^2/2$ is negative). The reason for this is that the total energy in this case is not bounded from below. The total energy can become as negative as you would like (since the potential is negative).

You can think about a marble rolling **down** a downward-facing parabola, rather than a marble rolling back-and-forth in an upward-facing parabola.